# Play framework 2 scala templates - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scala, backbone.js, playframework-2.0

I tried to Google but couldn't find much. I'm playing with play 2 framework and it provides you scala templates. I'm thinking to use backbone for my next project which comes with underscore templates.

How do scala templates compare with underscore templates? Which one should I use and why for heavy JSON based front end application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Scala templates are **server side**
- Underscore templates are **client-side**.

There is no further comparison possible.

Answer (score 1):

Scala templates are server side and underscore templates are client side so they gets compiled by JavaScript. Therefore you can't manipulate scala templates as you do underscore.